# Using Google search api

Tags: java, api, search

Should I expect to obtain exactly the same results with Google search api as I obtain searching directly on Google? I have a Java application that uses the Google search api, I mean http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0..... but I get one search item skipped and several in a different order.

Comment: You can try creating your own [google scraper with python](http://blog.goog.io/web/scraping/2019/12/30/how-to-scrape-google-with-python.html) or you can use a third [party google search api](https://rapidapi.com/apigeek/api/google-search3)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should expect the same result.

If you search Google with your browser then Google would extract some data from browser and based on that adjust results to fit you better. This is not happening with Java application.

Comment: I see... Yes, it may depend on who is doing the search using the browser... Ok, thank you for the answer!

Answer (score -1):

Try this might be help you.

```
<form method="get" action="http://www.google.com/search">

<input type="text"   name="q" size="31" maxlength="255" value="" />
<input type="submit" value="Google Search" />
<br />
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you. Can you get the search results in a file instead of the browser?

Comment: Monica, I don't have much idea about java. But to get results in file php have functions like CURL() or file_get_contents() so you should find similar functions that works with java.

Comment: I did write a Java application that searches using Google directly, and not using the Google api. But there are certain queries for which it does not return any results (although it should.) Also, it may return results now, but no results  a minute later. Any help to handle these situations? I would appreciate it very much. I start by building a URL object like this: URL url = new URL("https://www.google.com/search?v=1.0&userip=76.88.34.11&start=" + n + "&num=1&q=resume+filetype%3Apdf");